# Reading an HTML input field entered without a final Return

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an input element in  this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/stevea/DLe3a/9. If I enter Return after putting something in the field I trigger the change handler and pick up and display the value fine:

```
$(function() {
    $('input#fname').change(function(e) {
        $('div#firstName').append(this.value);
    });
```

But what if the user forgets to hit return and closes down the page? I want to come back, in that case, when I sense the page shutting down, and pull out what was entered into the Input field without a Return.

Can I do that?  In the jsfiddle I have a button and its handler.  Assuming the button click is shutting down the page, how would I respond to the button click to get the value sitting in the input field?

Thanks

Comment: instead of `this.value` you can stick with jQuery `$(this).val()`

Comment: I'm already given -this- coming into the handler so I thought that sticking with it would save jQuery the trouble of building a wrapped set around it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this sir

```
   $(function() {
    $("#fname").change(function(e) {
        $("#firstName").append(this.value)
    });

    $("#getInput").click(function (e)  {
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To detect if the page is closing, use the `.unload()` event

```
$(window).unload(function() {
    var input = $('#fname').val();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you want to do some code when the window is pre-closed.

Here is some sample code: [jsDiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DLe3a/7/)

```
$('#fname').change(function () {
    $('#firstName').append(this.value);
});

window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
    var e = e || window.event;
    // get input #fname
    $('#firstName').append($('#fname').val());
    // do something you want before the window closes

    // show confirm message (optional) - if you don't want show message, return '';
    //IE & Firefox
    if (e) {
        e.returnValue = 'You have some unfilled inputs!';
    }

    // For Safari
    return 'You have some unfilled inputs!';
};
```

Comment: The div for firstName is not cleared when it inputs something , but a nice codes bro

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't detecting a page closing down.  The problem is to capture an Input field's content when something external happens before the user enters Return.  But after playing around with it more, at this jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/stevea/bT54M/3/ - it turns out that there really is no problem.  If you're in the middle of entering text into an Input field and you do something external, like hitting the Get Input button in the jsfiddle above, the change event for the Input is triggered automatically and `this.value` is what you've entered so far. So the bottom line is that you don't need to hit Return when you're done.  Just about anything you do outside of the Input (probably anything that blurs the Input focus) triggers the Input change event.

```
$(function() {

    $('input#fname').change(function(e) {
        debugger;
        $('div#firstName').append(this.value);
    });

    $('#getInput').click(function() {
         debugger;
         $('div#firstName').append(this.value);

    });
});
```